# Questions about wiring raspberry, l298n, SG90 and HC-SR04

Tags: sensor, wiring, servo

I've finished testing and mounting my hc-sr04 and sg90 and now i have to connect everything, but have doubts and questions. Here are the diagrams that show what I am thinking to do:
This one shows how I would like to connect either the SG90 or the HC-SR04
[image]

This one shows how I would like to connect both the SG90 and HC-SR04 to the L298N
[image]

The L298N is powered by 2x3.7V 18650 batteries(chinese brand) and it drives 2xDC wheels.
I would like to know if:

- the wiring in both cases is correct?
- there is any benefit from one of them over the other?
- there are any risks I should consider when connecting SG90, HC-SR04 or other similar +5V devices to the L298N?
- I connect both devices to the L298N can I have som problems like heating or malfunctioning of the L298N?
- using a Power bank(2600/5000mHa) to power the Pi which one will consume more power, e.g. will one of them cause my battery the exhaust faster? Given the fact that the HC-SR04 will be used more often in order to detect obstacles.
  There is also a Raspberry camera connected to the Pi camera slot.
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sets of wiring look okay as far as I can tell with one minor proviso.

It is safer to use a voltage divider (pair of resistors) on the HC-SR04 echo line to cut the voltage from 5V to 3V3.  A single resistor will give some protection if >5k or so, but a proper divide is better.

I can't remember how much 5V power the 5V on-board regulator of the common L298N motor driver boards can supply.  It'll probably be enough for a small 9g servo.

Comment: I have a 1K resistor between Echo and IN pin on the Pi. You say that I need >5K, so I need to look for another resistor?(I do not have a spare one) From your answer I assume that I cannot connect both the HC-SR04 and SG90 to the +5V of the L298N?

Comment: According to my limited knowledge the current flow will be (5V-3.3V)/1000 amps with a 1k resistor, or 1.7 mA.  You should be aiming for less then 0.5 mA.  See http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications

Comment: Ok, that makes things more clear for me. Can I assume that this power devider circuit will be safe http://www.modmypi.com/blog/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi ?

Comment: @archer66 As far as I am aware the pair of resistors to form a voltage divider is by far the most common solution to drop 5V to 3.3V for the Pi.  It is perfectly safe.